# Не работает localStorage.setItem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет всем!
Не работает `localStorage.setItem` не могу понять в чем причина. При клике все работает а вот после обновления в браузере все классы исчезают,а должен было сохранятся.
Спасибо

```
// Product Grid
$('#grid-view').click(function() {
    // What a shame bootstrap does not take into account dynamically loaded columns
    $('#content .list-product').attr('class', 'col-md-4 col-sm-6 product_main grid-product');
    $('#list-view').removeClass('active');
    $('#grid-view').addClass('active');

    localStorage.setItem('display', 'list');
});

if (localStorage.getItem('display') == 'list') {
    $('#list-view').trigger('click');
    $('#list-view').addClass('active');
} else {
    $('#grid-view').trigger('click');
    $('#grid-view').addClass('active');
}

// Product List
$('#list-view').click(function() {
    //$('#content .product-grid > .clearfix').remove();

    $('#content .row > .grid-product').attr('class', 'col-md-12 product_main list-product');
    $('#grid-view').removeClass('active');
    $('#list-view').addClass('active');

    localStorage.setItem('display', 'list');
});
```

Comment: проверь что эти элементы уже существуют в DOM в момент проверки. Возможно стоит поместить проверку в `$(function(){...})` если она еще не там, либо перед закрывающим тегом body

Comment: ну и поставить `if (localStorage.getItem('display') == 'list') { ...` после обоих `$(...).click(function() { ...`